# What functions $f$ satisfy $f(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)= 0$ iff $a_1=a_2=\cdots a_n$

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find real-valued functions $f(a_1,...,a_n)$ such that $f(a_1,...,a_n) = 0$ (or $\min f$ is achieved) if and only if $a_1=\cdots a_n$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$. One function could be $f = |a_1-a_2|+|a_2-a_3|+\cdots |a_{n-1}-a_n|$, and also $f = (a_1-a_2)^2+\cdots$. What are other types of functions that satisfy such condition?

Comment: This is a pretty open-ended question. Are there specific properties you are looking for?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip At the moment any forms of such functions are ok, but it's better if the functions are in simpler forms, although I'm not sure there exist such functions that are simpler than what I suggested..

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Actually, it'd be great if the function is concave to a Hermitian operator $A$ if we denote $a_i = \text{Tr}(A E_i)$ where $E_i$ are also Hermitian matrices

Answer (score 1):

What about $\max(|a|_1, \ldots, |a|_n)$ or $\max(a_1, \ldots, a_n, -a_1, \ldots, -a_n)$?